# Version chapters and add version number to footer of every chapter

Tags: header-footer, chapters, titlesec, document-classes

I would like to manually version chapters in my document and add the corresponding version number of a chapter to its footer. Say I have two chapters, 1 and 2, chapter 1 has version 2.0, and chapter 2 has version 3.0. I would like the footer of chapter 1 to show : Version 2.0, and footer of chapter 2 to say: Version 3.0. I would like to manually define the versions, not use VCS version.

I can't use `fancyhdr` because I use `titlesec` and they conflict:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/ttlps.def:261: Package titlesec Error: Incompatible package.
/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/ttlps.def:262: Package titlesec Error: Incompatible package.
```

This is my `thesis.cls` class (minimal working example, I stripped irrelevant parts like colors etc):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesis}
\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{book}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[polish,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage[outermarks,pagestyles,clearempty,psfloats,rigidchapters,%
   newlinetospace]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{SREBRO}{cmyk}{0.47,0.37,0.38,0.09}

\newcommand{\secfont}{\fontfamily{fla}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\chnfont}{\fontfamily{fla}\selectfont}
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
% Widows and orphans (club lines):
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300
% Page layout:
\newlength{\headindent}
\setlength{\headindent}{2.5cm}
\widenhead{\headindent}{0pt}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2.8cm,lmargin=4.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headsep=35pt,
  footskip=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm,reversemarginpar,marginparwidth=2.5cm,
  marginparsep=0.5cm, asymmetric}
\DeclareOption{oneside}{%
  \geometry{twoside=false,lmargin=5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm}}
% Titles:
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]{\secfont\Huge\filleft}{}{0em}{%
  \parbox{0.9\textwidth}%
  {\raggedleft\chnfont\fontsize{65}{50}\selectfont%
    \textcolor{SREBRO}{\thechapter}}%
  \vspace{0.5ex}\\}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]{\secfont\Huge\filleft}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-\headindent}{0.5cm}{7cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\addvspace{1.8ex}\secfont\bfseries}%
  {\contentslabel{1.5em}}{\hspace*{-1.5em}}%
  {~\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{0.3ex}]
% Page styles:
\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{}{}\setfoot{}{}{}}
\renewpagestyle{empty}{\sethead{}{}{}\setfoot{}{}{}}
\newcommand{\setdefmainpagestyle}{%
  \sethead[\large\usepage][]%
  [\footnotesize\itshape
    \if@mainmatter
      \ifthenelse{\value{chapter}>0}{\thechapter~~}{}
    \fi
    \chaptertitle]%
  {\footnotesize\itshape
    \if@mainmatter
      \ifthesection%
        {\thesection~~\sectiontitle}%
        {\ifthenelse{\value{chapter}>0}{\thechapter~~}{}\chaptertitle}
    \else
      \chaptertitle
    \fi
  }{}{\large\usepage}
  \setfoot{version 3 \today}{}{}
  %\setfloathead{}{}{}{\setheadrule{0pt}}[p]
}
\newpagestyle{main}{\setdefmainpagestyle}
\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{main}\raggedbottom}
\let\setminus\backslash
%
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Some example main.tex:

```
\documentclass{thesis}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example rather than just code fragments. This will make it much easier for people to help. Also, why can't you use `fancyhdr` with `titlesec`? `titleps` is probably a better option for full functionality, but I've not heard that `fancyhdr` can't be used at all.

Comment: If you use `titlesec`, then you can use the related `titleps` package for your headers and footers. I don't think you need anything particularly fancy if you are manually setting the version number for each chapter....

Comment: @cfr I provided a minimal working example.

Comment: `titlesec` doesn't conflict. `titleps` conflicts`, which `titlesec` is being told to load by the `pagestyles` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: versioned chapters]

Note that your code would not compile if a chapter contained more than one page, so I modified it to make it work. (Probably you omitted a needed package.)

```
\chapterversion{<version>}
```

sets the chapter version which is then added as the bottom right footer when the default page style for main pages is active.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}
\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{book}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[polish,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage[outermarks,pagestyles,clearempty,psfloats,rigidchapters,%
   newlinetospace]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{SREBRO}{cmyk}{0.47,0.37,0.38,0.09}

\newcommand{\secfont}{\fontfamily{fla}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\chnfont}{\fontfamily{fla}\selectfont}
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
% Widows and orphans (club lines):
\widowpenalty=300
\clubpenalty=300
% Page layout:
\newlength{\headindent}
\setlength{\headindent}{2.5cm}
\widenhead{\headindent}{0pt}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2.8cm,lmargin=4.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headsep=35pt,
  footskip=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm,reversemarginpar,marginparwidth=2.5cm,
  marginparsep=0.5cm, asymmetric}
\DeclareOption{oneside}{%
  \geometry{twoside=false,lmargin=5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm}}
% Titles:
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]{\secfont\Huge\filleft}{}{0em}{%
  \parbox{0.9\textwidth}%
  {\raggedleft\chnfont\fontsize{65}{50}\selectfont%
    \textcolor{SREBRO}{\thechapter}}%
  \vspace{0.5ex}\\}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[block]{\secfont\Huge\filleft}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-\headindent}{0.5cm}{7cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\addvspace{1.8ex}\secfont\bfseries}%
  {\contentslabel{1.5em}}{\hspace*{-1.5em}}%
  {~\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{0.3ex}]
% Page styles:
\renewpagestyle{plain}{\sethead{}{}{}\setfoot{}{}{}}
\renewpagestyle{empty}{\sethead{}{}{}\setfoot{}{}{}}
\newcommand{\setdefmainpagestyle}{%
  \sethead[\large\usepage][]%
  [\footnotesize\itshape
    \if@mainmatter
      \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\thechapter~~\fi
    \fi
    \chaptertitle]%
  {\footnotesize\itshape
    \if@mainmatter
      \ifthesection%
        {\thesection~~\sectiontitle}%
        {\ifnum\value{chapter}>0\thechapter~~\chaptertitle\fi}%
    \else
      \chaptertitle
    \fi
  }{}{\large\usepage}%
  \setfoot{version 3 \today}{}{\ifx\thesis@chapterversion\@empty\relax\else chapter version \thesis@chapterversion \fi}%
  %\setfloathead{}{}{}{\setheadrule{0pt}}[p]
}
\newpagestyle{main}{\setdefmainpagestyle}
\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{main}\raggedbottom}
\let\setminus\backslash
%
\let\thesis@chapterversion\@empty
\newcommand*\chapterversion[1]{\gdef\thesis@chapterversion{#1}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{\jobname}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter 1}\chapterversion{3.0}
\kant[1-5]
\chapter{Chapter 2}\chapterversion{2.0}
\kant[6-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great but can you also add version on the chapter's title page ?

Comment: Just change the `plain` style rather than the default one as `plain` is used for the first page of chapters by default.